# Remove single character from a string?

Tags: c#, string

How would you remove a single character from a string?

```
string = string.Remove(3);
```

but it removes the third char and everything else.

Comment: @SLaks: Those type of comments help no one. At least link to the documentation for canonical reference. (I'm not defending the bad question, just mentioning something bad I see all the time in the Python section) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx

Comment: Too bad the general reference close reason was effectively abolished...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the remove method [signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk.aspx):

```
public string Remove(
    int startIndex,
    int count
)
```

you need to provide a second parameter as the total number of characters to remove from `startIndex`:

```
string = string.Remove(3, 1);
```

Comment: If you don't use the second parameter Remove() will return the removed character back.
e.g:
`var word = "bill".Remove('b');`
word will equal "b"

Answer (score 4):

```
string = string.Remove(3, 1);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`string = string.Remove(3,1);`

Answer (score 0):

Speaking theory, String.Remove() "does not" remove anything as strings are immutable.  In the background it creates a new instance of string with the character(s) removed.

But, for the purpose you mentioned you can use String.Remove(3,1) to remove a single character.