# Why my string.Remove() is not working as expected?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to solve this problem of finding if two words are anagrams of one another (if we rearrange a string, it matches second string).

Based on [**Remove single character from a string**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963738/remove-single-character-from-a-string) I built my own function:

```
public class AreAnagrams
{
        public static bool AreStringsAnagrams(string FirstString, string SecondString)
        {
            if (FirstString == null || b == null)
                return false;

            if (FirstString.Length != SecondString.Length)
                return false;

            for (int i = 0; i < SecondString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (FirstString.IndexOf(SecondString[i]) == -1)
                    return false;
                else
                    FirstString.Remove(FirstString.IndexOf(SecondString[i]), 1); // Here it does not modify FirstString, even if I put 2nd parameter as 1
            }

            if (FirstString.Length > 0)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(AreStringsAnagrams("neural", "unreal"));
    }
}
```

On my watch I see `FirstString` still as is. What is the problem? Please and thank you

Comment: See the [manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx): use the return value.

Comment: C# strings are immutable. string.Remove returns a new string with the removed characters.

Comment: See documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ad138yc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're looking for a better solution, just sort the characters in the strings and see if they're the same...

    `var first = new string(FirstString.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());
    var second = new string(SecondString.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c).ToArray());

    bool areAnagrams = (first == second);`

Comment: Or a one-liner: `return first.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c).SequenceEqual(second.ToLower().OrderBy(c => c));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the result to `FirstString`

```
FirstString = FirstString.Remove(FirstString.IndexOf(SecondString[i]), 1);
```

Comment: Downvoter: in what way is this answer not useful or incorrect?

Comment: @BobKaufman Downvoting is necessary in order to be able to delete.